# Data from the Form Submit vs Data from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm trying to implement reCAPTCHA in my MVC site, but it doesn't Validate unless I submit it from a form, like this:

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("VerifyCaptcha", "Signup") )
    { 
        @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "clean", publicKey: "6LcnfAITAAAAAAY--6GMhuWeemHF-rwdiYdWvO-9");
        <input type="submit" id="btnVerify" value="Verify" />
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PolicyModel model)
    {
        var result = ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "THE_KEY");
        return View();
    }
```

I don't want to use form submission because I don't want to return a new view. All my data is being pushed around with ajax in json form. What I'd like to do is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'verifyCaptcha',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('There was a problem verifying your captcha. Please try again.');
    }
});
return valid;

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VerifyCaptcha()
        {
            var result = ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "THE_KEY");

            return Json(result);
        }
```

The ajax call gets to the controller, but the Validation method completes immediately, almost as if it doesn't even get to making the request. I'm not sure why the validation always fails if the captcha isn't in a form - is it perhaps losing information like it's public key or something? Is there a workaround to this?

**Edit: Added the ajax controller action method without model.**

Comment: change the button type to button and in your ajax assign a valid url, write ajax inside your button click event

Comment: so you set `type : 'POST'`in your ajax code? putting you code in a completed state make easier to help you

Comment: ok, your ajax request reach the `Action`or does not ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have a feeling it loses the public key or something, because it ALWAYS returns false, so quickly that it seems as though it's not even submitting the request.

Comment: you have to send the public key in the data property as a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) or [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and change your ajax request to

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'verifyCaptcha',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: $('form').serializeArray(), // $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
});
```

You haven't added the data part in your request. That seems to be the problem

Comment: You Sir, are the person who has made my Monday bearable. Works perfectly - thanks a ton! Can you perhaps shed some light as to why I actually need to pass the form as data?

Comment: Simple reason. You need `data` to validate the request. But since you want it as a form response, you need to build your data object and send it via AJAX. And since you are using jQuery, you can use the built-in functionality to get the data from your form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Ajax Request with all parameters for a form request. For example the content-type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Look at this: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

UPDATE:
...and yes ...you must do a POST request, and not a GET.

UPDATE:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'verifyCaptcha',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('ERROR', response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, just saw you edit. It's more complete but still wrong: try with `content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: Okay, I did that. Still a problem.

Comment: Check what `alert('ERROR', response);` show. In that `response ` there's the code of the error and then you could find more info about the problem.

Comment: Nothing is wrong my ajax call. The server-side call for Validate always just returns false.